# How to changer innerText to php function using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have to program a website containing a calendar with events, with the possibility to cycle through months, this calendar being generated by php function, I am trying to add an eventListener to a div so that when I click it, it would cycle through the months, generating each time a new calendar.

After a bit of research I found out that I needed to use AJAX but I can't really figure out how to use it.

Here is my code:

```
let next = document.getElementById("buttonNext");

let monthNb = String(new Date().getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
let yearNb = new Date().getFullYear();

next.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    monthNb++;

    If (monthNb > 12) {
        yearNb++;
    }
                           // I know I am trying to send js var as php but idk ;-;         v      v 
    document.getElementById("calendarContainer").innerText = '<?php echo createCalendar(yearNb, monthNb); ?>';
});
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<div class="button_leftRight"><img src="icons/left" id="buttonBack"></div>
<div class="button_leftRight"><img src="icons/right" id="buttonNext"></div>
<div id="calendarContainer">
    <?php
    echo createCalendar($year, $month);
    ?>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time ! Hopefully will find a good solution ! :D

PS : if you need any more infos, let me know, I might forget things, its the first time I post a thread

Comment: You need *ajax* to do this.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte.is right. ajax is here your friends. Take a look at this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: you mention `ajax` but have none here. Essentially the PHP will run on the server at some location. Send an ajax request to that location with whatever parameters are appropriate and use the response (ie: printed by PHP ) in your ajax callback function

Comment: What's your exact question about this? There are a lot of tutorials out there about AJAX - what have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `Fetch` api and send POST requests to the PHP script you could try like this - untested:

```
<?php

    # calendar.php ~ obviously there will need to be MORE code than this...

    if( SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['year'],$_POST['month']) ){
        #ensure no extra data is sent back - flush buffers
        ob_clean();

        #send a response
        exit( createCalendar( $_POST['year'], $_POST['month'] ) );
    }

?>
```

And the Javascript to send the AJAX request using `Fetch`

```
let next = document.getElementById("buttonNext");
let monthNb = String(new Date().getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
let yearNb = new Date().getFullYear();



next.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    monthNb++;

    If (monthNb > 12) {
        yearNb++;
    }
    let fd=new FormData();
        fd.append('year',yearNb);
        fd.append('month',monthNb);
        
    fetch( '/path/to/calendar.php', {method:'post',body:fd})
        .then( res=>res.text() )
        .then( text=>{
            document.getElementById("calendarContainer").innerHTML=text
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do the ajax and many optimization that you can do but I am giving you a simple guideline on how to do it. The simplest way to do it is create a php file lets name it ajax.php in the web server whose content is

```
<?php echo createCalendar($_GET['year'], $_GET['month']); ?>
```

Then, in your js code make an ajax call to that ajax.php file for eg:

```js
let next = document.getElementById("buttonNext");

let monthNb = String(new Date().getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
let yearNb = new Date().getFullYear();

next.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    monthNb++;

    If (monthNb > 12) {
        yearNb++;
    }
      
   fetch(`ajax.php?year=${yearNb}&month=${monthNb}`, {
      method: 'GET', 
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    .then(response => {
      document.getElementById("calendarContainer").innerText = response;
    }).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
});
```